# Calling a JavaScript function with a return statement on another script

Tags: javascript, function

```
<body>      
<script>;

      function myfunction() { 
        num1 = 8
        num2 = 25
        num3 = 10


        return (num1 * num2) + num3)
    }
    document.write(myfunction()) 
    </script>

    <script>
    myfunction() 
    </script>
</body>
```

I'm currently learning JavaScript and I have problem calling the function on another script.

Comment: You really should learn about `getElementById()`. It'll spare you a lot of messy code

Comment: `this code only works with document.write` what?

Comment: What exactly isn’t working? There’s no such thing as `getElementByID`. You mean `getElementById`. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors, as you try stuff, then tell us about your _specific_ problem, and your goal.

Comment: I've commented the return statement on my code because my code won't run if I include the `return`. What I would like to do is omit the `document.write((num1 * num2) + num3)` and replace it with the `return (num1 * num2) + num3)`, but if I use it, my script won't display any result

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine, you just missed a parenthesis,
you used:

```
return (num1 * num2) + num3)
```

should be:

```
return ((num1 * num2) + num3)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are in trouble because you got a ; at the beginning of your script and it miss a ( in your return.

```
<body>      
<script>

      function myfunction() { 
        num1 = 8
        num2 = 25
        num3 = 10

        //document.write((num1 * num2) + num3) 
        return ((num1 * num2) + num3)
    }
    //document.write(myfunction()) //this code works with document.write
    </script>

    <script>
    var myres = myfunction() //this code only works with document.write
    </script>
</body>
```

Work for me !

Comment: A semicolon at the beginning doesn’t affect anything.

Comment: Thanks @Xufox, but can I call the `function` just by its name `myfunction()`? Without the variable declaration.

Comment: @Ricky That depends on how you’re going to use the return value of `myfunction`.

Comment: I just wanted to display the result of the function just by calling it without the need of declaring a variable or adding a `write` method...